# Crashlytics send email regarding a crash. But there are no crash same as the email

Tags: android, email, crashlytics, google-fabric

I received a Crashlytics email notification for New Fatal Issue for my Android app

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FdkT.jpg

But when I open "Learn More", Crashlytics stated there is no crash at all

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkDdg.jpg

Have anyone encountered this before?
Do anyone know what is going on?
It happen to me twice already

Comment: Could be related to the current production issue where there is a delay in crashes showing up on the dashboard. http://status.fabric.io/incidents/6m41dwk24d04

Comment: @MikeBonnell. The status is not clear enough to confirm this tho :/

Comment: I'd recommend contacting support(at)fabric(dot)io if you continue to not see crashes that you're being notified of.